# Word count after zgrep

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm a little confused as to what this counts:

```
zgrep -B 4 "xyz" <filename> | grep -i abcd | wc -l
```

Does it count the occurences of abcd in the 4 lines xyz? "wc -l" returns a different count than the number of lines present inside the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prints every 'xyz' and 4 lines before from the file.

`zgrep -B 4 "xyz" <filename>`

Prints only lines, containing (case-insensitive) 'abcd'.

`grep -i abcd`

Counts the lines.

`wc -l`

All in all, it shows how many case-insensitive 'abcd' line can be find in file being withing 4 lines before 'xyz'.

Answer (score 0):

It counts the number of `abcd` strings in the result of your first `zgrep -B 4 "xyz" <filename>` filter operation.

`zgrep -B 4 "xyz" <filename>` 
 will return all lines with the `"xyz"` string and the four lines that precede them if they exist.